# What wrote this apology letter?

Tags: riddle

> Dear friend,
>
> You've heard the malicious gossip by now, and
>   Although I didn't start it, I must confess that
>   Several times I actively participated in it.
>
> I've come to think you are very self-centered,
>   Since it seems like every time you talk about me,
>   You feel the need to also mention yourself!
>
> Still, I write this now in guilt and distress.
>   I want you to know that I'm part of the solution
>   And not part of the overall larger problem.
>
> Forgive me- I know you can identify with me, so
>   Think about the good times when we first met:
>   The sense of self-empowerment you had then!
>
> Though I'm a pro, and I was in the top 10 in my class,
>   Oddly, I feel larger and more together when I'm alone.
>   When I'm around friends I feel small and disconnected.
>
> In loving apology,
>   me

---

### What wrote this apology letter?

Comment: I think the real question is what did it write it to?

Comment: @Raystafarian u

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> **The letter I**

You've heard the malicious gossip by now, and
Although I didn't start it, I must confess that
Several times I actively participated in it.

> **I** doesn't start "the mal**i**c**i**ous goss**i**p," but is in the phrase 3 times

I've come to think you are very self-centered,
Since it seems like every time you talk about me,
You feel the need to also mention yourself!

> You mention yourself == I think etc or general i, I confusion

Still, I write this now in guilt and distress.
I want you to know that I'm part of the solution
And not part of the overall larger problem.

> **I** is in "gu**i**lt" and "d**i**stress," and is in "the solut**i**on," but not in "the overall larger problem"

Forgive me- I know you can identify with me, so
Think about the good times when we first met:
The sense of self-empowerment you had then!

> I identify as I. (self empowerment referring to babies realizing they exist separate from the world sort of)

Though I'm a pro, and I was in the top 10 in my class,
Oddly, I feel larger and more together when I'm alone.
When I'm around friends I feel small and disconnected.

> Pronoun is a professional noun apparently. 9th letter. I (larger and in one piece) is I but in words it's lowercase i (two parts --disconnected --, smaller).

So the true answer:

> Going hamateur wrote it, cause I did.

Comment: under 7 minutes. nicely done!

Comment: "Though I'm a pro, and I was in the top 10 in my class,
Oddly, I feel larger and more together when I'm alone.
When I'm around friends I feel small and disconnected." was a big hint but for some reason I was thinking about it being eye. I think it was cause of "I know you can identify with me"

Comment: @JLee Edited for the profesional nouners in the house

Comment: The answer is not in vowels. http://xkcd.com/1562/

Comment: I feel like the together/alone explanation could be better.

Comment: @dennisdeems you are correct sir.